# Can XAML ItemTemplate be used recursively?

Tags: templates, winrt-xaml, recurrence

I wonder if this is at all possible, I get only a partly result on the View, so I doubt... but perhaps someone has an improvement to this codesnippet.

The View contains a ListView that is binding to an ItemsSource and it points to an ItemTemplate like so:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyData.SubOrdinates}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
```

The datasource is a list of person objects, with one person at the toplevel. Each of the persons contain a property "SubOrdinates", except of course the persons at the lowest level. The subordinates property is a list of person objects. The template to show the data is like so:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>               
            <ListView ItemsPanel="{Binding SubOrdinates}" ItemTemplate="{Binding MyTemplate}"/>
        </StackPanel>                       
    </DataTemplate>
```

I guess it is obvious what I'm looking for: to show the Name of a superior, followed by a list of Names of his subordinates. Then the next superior and so on.

The result I get, is that only the top level superiors' names are shown, but not their subordinates, with their subordinates etc...

Is this recurring call of templates at all possible? 
Suggestions for improvement?

Regards,Peter

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do: Use a `DataTemplateSelector`.

### Selector

```
public class MyDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate MyTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return MyTemplate;
    }
}
```

### Xaml

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>               
        <ListView ItemsPanel="{Binding SubOrdinates}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"/>
    </StackPanel>                       
</DataTemplate>

<namespace:MyDataTemplateSelector x:Key="MyDataTemplateSelector"
                                  MyTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"/>
```

Then you can use it in another `ListView` or `ContentControl` like this (after setting `ItemsSource`/`Content`):

```
<ListView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyDataTemplateSelector}"/>
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks @Nate Diamond! Your answer set me on the right track. I had to figure out some specific details, but in the end I have got it working like you suggested. Good job!